# Why does my player's speed decreASE hugely on collision with this platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

In my game I have platforms that move from point a to point b, and when the player lands on the platform for some reason his speed his massively reduced while he is on it.

The code for the moving platform:

```
private void Start()
{
    isActive = true;
}

void Update()
{
    if (isActive == true)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pos1, pos2, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1.0f));
    }

}`
```

The player has code which makes him a child of the platform on collision to ensure it doesn't fall off the platform. :

```
if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("MGround"))
{
     landEffect.Play();
     playerSpeed = 8;
     this.transform.parent = other.transform;
     isJumping = false;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `playerSpeed = 8;` part?

Comment: @MathewHD i added that to combat the speed reduction :)

Comment: Why exactly shouldn't the player be able to fall off the platform?

Answer (score 0):

You could get around this problem, if you cache the velocity of the rigidbody of your player if he collides with the platform set the rigidbody velocity to the cached value. [Rigidbody.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

```
// Put this somewhere in your Player script
private Vector3 tmpPlayerVelocity;
void LateUpdate() 
{
    tmpPlayerVelocity = yourPlayerRigidbody.velocity;
}

// Put this after your collision code
yourPlayerRigidbody.velocity = tmpPlayerVelocity;
```

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, ill leave the answer though, if it works for someone else